# how do I get a smooth bullet spiral in java?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, trigonometry

I'm trying to make a 2D shmup.
The code works fine, but when I use a timer it gives a very choppy spyral even if I just add simply one angle per loop.

The bullets use Math.sin and Math.cos and add them to x/y coordinates.

Here it's my code:

http://pastebin.com/8HKR7pLs
Enemy projectile

http://pastebin.com/WYJfhQwk
Enemy

EDIT:

```
public Enemy_Projectile(float x2, float y2, float f_angle)
        {
                x = x2;
                y = y2;
                angle = f_angle;
                offscreen = false;
                width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
                height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                x_angle = (float) Math.sin(angle);
                y_angle = (float) Math.cos(angle);
         }

public void AddBullet()
        {
                angle += 1;
                if (angle > 360)
                {
                        bullet.cancel();
                }
                enemy_bullets.add(new Enemy_Projectile(AI.x, AI.y, angle));
        }
```

here it's how it looks:
[image: bullet pattern]

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a link to it.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix fixed.

Comment: Have you tried using finer detail?  ie using `angle += 0.1;` instead of `angle += 1;`?

Comment: oh, how silly of me, I though 1 degree was something really small, thanks.

Comment: Math. trig uses radians.  1 radian is about 1/6 of a circle

Comment: Whatsup with the `sin / cos`? LibGDX has `Vectors` for this stuff. No more radians, no more `sin` and `cos` but clear and understandable `Vector` math. It makes your life easier for these kind of rotations and eventually with everything else "coordinate related" since it already has functionality for operations like distance, rotating, adding, subtracting, length, normalizing, etc.

Comment: @MennoGouw I personally blame the lack of tutorial information which uses the `Libgdx` functions. I didn't come across those myself until it happened by accident (*which was after I implemented my own, so then I rewrote it*). Not sure whether tutorials just like to teach the basic math behind the functions, or aren't even aware of the functions. [MathUtils](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html) also has `sin/cos` stuff if vectors don't want to be messed with.